# VSTS - NUGET creation build number as version

Tags: nuget-package, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am setting up a continuous integration of my nuget packgae on VSTS, I am following the steps mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget to have build number as nuget version.

I am using 2.* of nuget pack with automatic package Versioning set to use the build number and build number format under options set to $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r).

But this does not effect my version it always comes to be same 2.0.1

I am unable to understand what additional task has to be done.

Comment: Have you reviewed [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/03/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-1/)?

Comment: I did but I could not see anything related to build number as automatic versioning, tell me if I missed something

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new build definition? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true)

Comment: Based on the log, the build number is 2.0.1-OnPremServicingFargo.28. What's the result if you try it with a new build definition? BTW: I can't access your VSTS.

Comment: When I try to create a new build even though the build number changes nuget gets versioned as 2.0.1 and nuget publish fails since it is same version. What I am really looking to get is a unique version from build number. May be like 2.0.1.28 and more over I am not clear by the build number is not $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r).

Comment: What's the build number of new build definition?

Comment: Based on the build log, the build number has been updated after building the solution. What's the detail code of each project file (e.g. Servicing.csproj, OnPremServicing.Tests.csproj ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build number has been updated by GitVersionTask. So, disable it by specifying UpdateAssemblyInfo to false.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <UpdateAssemblyInfo>false</UpdateAssemblyInfo>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Article: [GitVersionTask Conditional control tasks](http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/msbuild-task/#conditional-control-tasks).

If you don’t need to update the version, you can uninstall GitVersionTask package.